# Can you switch the determiner between -ein and an adjective?

Tags: adjective, conjunction

Are both of these sentences interchangeable?

1. Ich habe einen neue Auto gekauft.
2. Ich habe ein neuen Auto gekauft.

Ich the conjugation of -ein optional if the there is an adjective for the noun that can be used as a determiner?

Comment: Neither is correct. Only "Ich habe ein neues Auto gekauft." is valid. The conjugation is obligatory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The conjuggation of *ein* is not optional, and No, this sentences are not interchangeable. Both of your sentences are wrong.

A car can be:

- das Auto (neuter)
- die Karre (feminine) (*Karre* is a shabby car)
- der Wagen (masculine) (*Wagen* is often used for bigger limousines)

Obviously you mean

> I have bought a new car.

depending on the German word for *car* this can be:

> Ich habe **ein neues** Auto gekauft.
>   Ich habe **eine neue** Karre gekauft.
>   Ich habe **einen neuen** Wagen gekauft.

You always must decline all determines (i.e. the article and the attribute) according to the grammatical gender of the noun.

Comment: Nur Verben werden konjugiert.